# How do i move THOUSANDS of files to their own folders based on first name?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, directory, filenames

I'm looking to make a BATCH file in order move thousands of files into a NEW folder with the name based on the first word of the name.

example:

```
c:\Monkeys likes apples.jpg
c:\Monkeys likes bananas.jpg
c:\Elephants likes avocados.jpg
c:\Elephants likes Grapefruit.jpg
-->
C:\Monkeys\Monkeys likes apples.jpg
C:\Monkeys\Monkeys likes bananas.jpg
C:\Elephants\Elephants likes avocados.jpg
C:\Elephants\Elephants likes Grapefruit.jpg
```

The results should show a folder called 'Monkeys' and 'Elephants' with the files inside it.

This is what i used, although this isn't selecting the first word only properly.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set folderpath=G:\Emulator\GAMES\test\
for %%f in (%folderpath%\*.*) do (
  set "foldername=%%~nf"
  md "!foldername:~0,-3!" >nul 2>&1
  move "%%f" "!foldername:~0,-3!"
)
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: S.O. is about helping people fix their code, NOT about providing canned solutions. Please update your Q with what you think was your best understanding of solving the problem and people will help you. Then you can learn! Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "folderpath=G:\Emulator\GAMES\test\"
Pushd "%folderpath%"
For %%A in (*.jpg) do For /f %%B in ("%%~nA") Do (
  if not exist %%B md %%B  >nul 2>&1
  Echo move "%%~fA" %%B
  move "%%~fA" %%B
)
Popd
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It just shows 'The system cannot find the file x' on every single file in the folder.

Comment: @avaris Removed the wrong  `"usebackq"` should work now.

Comment: Thanks, it works although only for 90% of the files, the rest doesn't get placed inside a folder, all of them have gotten a folder created, but they don't get placed into it (multiple files in every folder - from what i can tell).

Comment: @avaris Any error messages or patterns what doesn't work?

Comment: The batch runs and finishes, it seems like it's just skipping it.

Comment: @avaris To debug run the batch from an open cmd window and append a pause to the end of the batch. It could also help to temporarily remove the redirections from the `if ... md` command.

Comment: Right, sorry. Yeah it does actually say "The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: @avaris To identify the problematic files I insert an additional echo in the loop above.

Comment: same response, "The system cannot find the path specified". instead of repeating it 50+ times it only showed it once now though.

Comment: @avaris Without knowing the real data it's difficult to help. Are there file names with chars like `<>&()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative method, how does it perform?

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "folderpath=G:\Emulator\GAMES\test"

For %%A In ("%folderpath%\* *.*") Do Call :Sub "%%A"
Timeout -1
Exit/B

:Sub
    Set "newfolder=%~n1"
    Set "newfolder=%newfolder: ="&:%"
    If Not Exist "%~dp1%newfolder%\" MD "%~dp1%newfolder%"
    Move %1 "%~dp1%newfolder%"
```

The above code looks specifically for filenames containing at least one space, if you wish to include every file, change `"%folderpath%\* *.*"` to `"%folderpath%\*.*"` on line 4.